# PXE boot fails over to preinstalled GRUB without error message

Tags: linux, boot, arch-linux, bootloader, pxe

I am following [this guide](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PXE) to boot up a minimal arch linux image via PXE. My system has an [ASUS F2A85V motherboard](https://www.asus.com/Motherboards/F2A85V/HelpDesk_Manual/).

When selecting the PXE boot in the boot menu, I get following output:

```
>>Start PXE over IPv4.
  Station IP address is 192.168.0.45
  Server IP address is 192.168.0.1
  NBP filename is /arch/boot/syslinux/lpxelinux.0
  NBP filesize is 74752 Bytes
 Downloading NBP file...
```

This text is on the screen for one frame of the video footage I had to take to decipher it. After that I get one frame with a cursor and then the GRUB of the already installed system is displayed.

The dnsmasq log reads:

```
DHCPDISCOVER(br0) 08:60:de:ad:be:ef
DHCPOFFER(br0) 192.168.0.45 08:60:de:ad:be:ef
DHCPREQUEST(br0) 192.168.0.45 08:60:de:ad:be:ef
DHCPACK(br0) 192.168.0.45 08:60:de:ad:be:ef
error 8 User aborted the transfer received from 192.168.0.45
failed sending /tftp/arch/boot/syslinux/lpxelinux.0 to 192.168.0.45
sent /tftp/arch/boot/syslinux/lpxelinux.0 to 192.168.0.45
```

So it seems the transfer has gone wrong at first and then was successful. I read that some PXE implementations request and abort the file once to obtain its size which would match the behavoir in the logs.
However, after that, I am lost. There are no messages that could indicate why the PXE boot ends here.

How do I find out what is going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this is embarrassing:

My system is using EFI and the setup described in the linked article is about legacy BIOS systems.

After swapping the boot path with the correct one (`EFI/boot/bootx64.efi`) I get readable error messages that I can google.